# perl waring : "Use of unintitialized value in string ne" for condition check for column with the null value

Tags: perl, warnings, dbi, dbix-class

I am trying to fetch certain column from a table , some of the column might have the null value.Hence before filling my main data, I am checking the hash for null value.As some of the key is having null value and giving warning.

Is there any way to check if the hash key has no value in it to prevent warning.

```
    my $counter = 1;
    while ( my $hashRef = $queryHandle1->fetchrow_hashref) {

       foreach my $key (keys %{$hashRef} ) {
        if ( $hashRef->{$key} ne "" ) { #some of the coloumn of table has null value
                    #warning is coming for the if check
            $dbData{$counter}{$key} = $hashRef->{$key};
        }
        else {
            $dbData{$counter}{$key} = "";
        }

       }
       $counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is: the `defined` function.

```
if (defined $hashRef->{$key}) {...}
```

Or, since `undef` evaluates to false, you can use the short-circuiting OR operator to assign something else in one step without an explicit check.

```
$dbData{$counter}{$key} = $hashRef->{$key} || '';
```

**Update:**

As suggested by the comments, the one-liner is dangerous if you have `0` values which also evaluate to false. So you can do this instead:

```
$dbData{$counter}{$key} = defined $hashRef->{$key} ? $hashRef->{$key} : '';
```

Comment: Or better yet, use the defined-or operator `//` for that last line of code (perl 5.10+ only) to avoid overwriting the number zero with the empty string…

Comment: @stevenl: Dangerous, as the string ”0” also evaluates as false, and for all you know may be a valid value for this column.

Comment: to check for *no* value, use exists, not defined (since a value can exist and not be defined)

Answer (score 1):

If testing for the value behaves as you like and you simply want to silence the warning, you can use `no warnings 'uninitialized'` in a small scope around your test. This is one of the least important warnings categories IMO; in fact I would almost call this a debugging feature rather than a proper warning.

That said, if what you are testing for is if the value is defined, you should use the `defined` function as stevenl suggests.

**Edit**

I'm not sure what the downvote is for, but let me echo a sentiment that is common around some of the Perl world. `warnings` (and `strict` for that matter) are great and should always be used, except when you know why to turn some small part of them off for a certain reason. Sometimes uninitialized values should be falsey and silent and that's ok. When you know that's what you want, just turn it off rather than jumping through `|| ''` hoops; its more self-documenting.